# VirtualBox communication from Linux to/from Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, samba

VirtualBox is running in Windows 7 as the host.  VirtualBox has the two modifications (one is called Guest Additions; don't remember the other).  The Virtual machine has "bridged" networking selected.  I have SAMBA set up (now, the problem may be here; it has been three or four years since I last did this) on the Linux guest machine.  Neither guest nor host sees the other.

From the Windows 7 command prompt, the IP address of the Linux guest pings.  The IP address of another computer (a separate Windows 7 on the wireless network) pings from the Linux guest.  (I have no idea what IP address the Windows 7 host itself has.  The output of "netstat" does not seem to be useful.)

So, it seem to me that *something* should be working.  The only workgroup on the LAN is inventively named WORKGROUP.  SMB4K should be seeing something.  There must be a simple setup step that I am missing.

(FWIW, there are two processes running smbd, and no process is running nmbd.  YaST says that nmbd is set to run.  I am not sure what this means.)

Comment: You need to report what two modifications exactly are installed if you want assistance.